# ASP.NET Friendly urls - drawbacks?

Tags: asp.net, nuget, package, friendly-url

I currently have a large scale web application and I'm investigating the possibility of using the impressive ASPNET.FriendlyUrls package from NuGet (http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingASPNETFriendlyUrlsCleanerURLsEasierRoutingAndMobileViewsForASPNETWebForms.aspx).

I notice that in order to force the user to the friend url it uses a 301 redirect to push them from (for example) /MyPage.aspx to /MyPage.  I don't want to unnecessarily increase server traffic with extra redirects, will it add any extra load on our servers by utilising this package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shouldn't add a significant amount of load at all, especially if you remember to always publicly (as in URLs you give out either manually or in the codebase for the website) use the friendly URL style anyway as that eliminates the need for the redirect.

Comment: Another point to consider is that web devs tend to use redirects fairly freely anyway :)  Redirect to a GET after a POST for example, or after successfully authenticating, or for security reasons etc.

Comment: Yea very true. I'm just trying to avoid adding extra redirects if I can avoid on an already busy server :) but as long as I haven't hard coded a reference to an <pagename>.aspx page then I think it should pretty much work as.  I'd really like to add this feature!  Although functionally there's nothing wrong with the .aspx page reference, I just think it looks better having friendly urls.